# Micronaut: Getting the content-length of a response in a filter

Tags: filter, content-length, micronaut

We have a Micronaut application where I'd like to have some additional metrics. We added a filter

```
@Filter("/**")
class MetricsHttpRequestFilter(private val meterRegistry: MeterRegistry) :
        OncePerRequestHttpServerFilter(), HttpServerFilter {
//...
}
```

to achieve that. Within that filter, I'd like to read the `Content-Length` of the response to be able to create histograms over the response size. I have working code which correctly reads sizes of responses, but doubt it is the right way to hold things.

some way deeper in the code:

```
    private fun success(httpResponse: HttpResponse<*>, httpMethod: String, requestPath: String) {
        val tags = getTags(httpResponse, httpMethod, requestPath)
        // TODO use content length header instead
        val size = if (httpResponse.getBody(ByteArray::class.java).isPresent()) {
            httpResponse.getBody(ByteArray::class.java).get().size
        } else {
            0
        }

        DistributionSummary.builder(metricName)
                .description("the response sizes of http requests")
                .tags(tags)
                .baseUnit("bytes")
                .maximumExpectedValue(1000000)
                .register(meterRegistry)
                .record(size.toDouble())
    }
```

We wanted to use `httpResponse.contentLength` directly, but that one always returns `-1`, although the response has a `Content-Length` header in the end with a correct size given (when using curl on the rest interface).
I doubt it's a good idea to get the body as byte array since we have some endpoints that work with publishers and the framework generally is (as far as I understand) reactive, which may mean that the response actually is not yet completely processed when the headers are being sent. We're fine with not getting the response size in these cases.

Changing the ordering of the filters did not help for getting the content-length. Any ideas? Hints on how/where the `Content-Length` header is constructed in Micronaut would help, too!